# touch urls on UIWebView, hook and change the prompted window itemscxh

Tags: iphone

If I touch urls on UIWebView and hold 2, 3 seconds, it will display an option window for url with items:

```
Open, Copy
```

Is it possible to change the items or add new option? Such as

```
Open, Copy, Download
```

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using UIKit's built in UIWebView, no.  The only way to do this would be to rewrite/subclass it, but that's going to be a massive pain.

Note: Open and download are *basically* the same thing in iOS.